# Buddypress Private Messages Loop not work

Tags: buddypress

It seems that the BuddyPress private message loop is not working correctly after an update. While message notifications are displayed, clicking on them results in a message saying "No new messages." Do you know the reason for this issue?
https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/loops-reference/the-private-messages-loop-bp_has_message_threads/

```
<?php if ( bp_has_message_threads() ) : ?>
 
  <div class="pagination-count">
    <?php bp_messages_pagination_count() ?>
  </div>
 
  <div class="pagination-links">
    <?php bp_messages_pagination() ?>
  </div>
 
  <ul id="message-threads">
  <?php while ( bp_message_threads() ) : bp_message_thread(); ?>
 
    <li>
      <!-- Example template tags you can use -->
      <?php bp_message_thread_id() ?>
      <?php bp_message_thread_has_unread() ?>
      <?php bp_message_thread_unread_count() ?>
      <?php bp_message_thread_avatar() ?>
      <?php bp_message_thread_from() ?>
      <?php bp_message_thread_last_post_date() ?>
      <?php bp_message_thread_view_link() ?>
      <?php bp_message_thread_subject() ?>
      <?php bp_message_thread_excerpt() ?>
      <?php bp_message_thread_delete_link() ?>
    </li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
 
<?php else: ?>
 
  <div id="message" class="info">
    <p>There are no messages to display.</p>
  </div>
 
<?php endif;?>
```